# Passing props between react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running through [this](https://youtu.be/iUPWpXsmuaM) tutorial on React currently and I'm getting an issue with events between 2 components.

Here is the first:

```
class TodoComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4']
    }
  }

  onDelete(item) {
    const updatedTodos = this.state.todos.filter((val, index) => {
      return item !== val;
    });
    this.setState({
      todos: updatedTodos
    });
  }

  render() {
    let todos = this.state.todos;
    todos = todos.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <TodoItem item={item} key={index} onDelete={this.onDelete}/>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div id="todo-list">
        <p>The busiest people have the most leisure...</p>
        <ul>{todos}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the second:

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  handleDelete() {
    this.props.onDelete(this.props.item);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <div className="todo-item">
          <span className="item-name">{this.props.item}</span>
          <span className="item-delete" onClick={this.handleDelete}> x </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: this is undefined
>
> bundle.js:10896:7

That line from the webpack bundle refers to the following method from the second module...

```
handleDelete() {
  this.props.onDelete(this.props.item);
}
```

Sorry if this ends up being an easy fix, this is day 1 with React for me.

Comment: Pass it like this: `this.onDelete.bind(this)`

Comment: That did not work, same error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have event handlers in React, you have to make sure to bind the correct value of `this` to those handlers.

There's various ways to do this, but one easy and common way is to wrap your handlers around an **arrow function**, which maintains the intended value for `this` in your handlers:

```
// TodoItem
<span className="item-delete" onClick={() => this.handleDelete()}> x </span>

// TodoComponent
<TodoItem item={item} key={index} onDelete={(item) => this.onDelete(item)}/>
```

The reason behind this is that the event handlers are called **asynchronously**, and the value of `this` is undefined in that context unless you take extra precautions to ensure that `this` points to the intended value.

Further reading (MDN): [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (see the section that talks about Arrow Functions)

**Edit:** I used your code to create this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8sv924o/) with a working example.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this got rid of the error but the item is not being removed

Comment: Maybe a typo? Try this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t8sv924o/ -- seems to be working

Comment: Ah, I was missing "item" when passing the prop, fixed now! Thank you for your help.